# Getting app stack configuration in Spryker

Tags: spryker

As I understand there is `\Spryker\Shared\Config\Config::get` method to access configuration stored in `config/Shared` dir. Does Spryker have anything similar to get values from `deploy.*.yml` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare variables in `deploy.*.yml`
You can use them to set ENV in docker sdk

Example for passing env from deploy file to yves

Open file deploy.yml and add configuration

```
regions:
    EU:
        config:
            something:
                my_key: value
```

Then create twig for env in docker configuration.
`docker/generator/src/templates/env/something/something.env.twig`

Content of file

```
SOMETHING_MY_KEY={{ serviceData['my_key'] }}
```

Open yves twig for environment variables
`docker/generator/src/templates/env/application/yves.env.twig`

And add include for template

```
{% include "env/something/something.env.twig" with {
    serviceData: project['regions']['EU']['config']['something'],
    serviceName: 'something'
} %}
```

Make sure to pass correct name to access twing template and serviceData later.

After that you can add env variable to config file (`config/Shared/config_*.php`)

```
$config['<Const for my module>'] = getenv('SOMETHING_MY_KEY');
```